# Toast Not sending parameter to page when clicked and app is already open C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, toast

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App that receives a push notification. When the toast is clicked, it opens the app and sends the parameter to a specific page. My problem is that it only works if the app is off when I click the toast. If the app is open when I receive the notification, and I click it, it directs me to the app, but does not send the parameter to the specific page (ImageFullScreen). Do you know what needs to be done to accomplish this?

App.Xaml.Cs:

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    public string NavigateText { get; set; }

    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

    }

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        var launchString = e.Arguments;
        (App.Current as App).NavigateText = launchString.ToString();

        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
        }


        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();
            // Set the default language
            rootFrame.Language = Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages[0];

            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }
        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();

    }
```

MainPage.Xaml.Cs:

```
    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((App.Current as App).NavigateText == "")
        {
            await RefreshTodoItems();
        }
        else
        {
            items2 = await todoTable
                .Where(todoItem => todoItem.Text == (App.Current as App).NavigateText)
                .ToCollectionAsync();
            TodoItem myItem = items2[0] as TodoItem;
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(ImageFullScreen), myItem);
        }           
    }
```

ImageFullScreen.Xaml.Cs:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var myObject = (TodoItem)e.Parameter;
        img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(myObject.ImageUri));

        (App.Current as App).NavigateText = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `if (rootFrame.Content == null)` in the `OnLaunched` method is not executed because the app was already open (the content of the frame was the page). Only the window is activated and the `OnNavigatedTo` method in `MainPage` is not called.

You can try to initiate the navigation in the `OnLaunched` method always like this (without the if statement):

```
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
// Ensure the current window is active
Window.Current.Activate();
```